# Include *.resource.dll in nuget packages

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

When creating nuget package, I want to include all resources files.
Is it possible without specify one by one with  tag in the .nuspec file ?

Maybe with wildcards ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use some form of a wildcard. Here's an [example I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-localized-packages).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>...
    </metadata>
    <files>
    <file src="lib\**" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```